# CheckBox List Tile add selected value to different list

Tags: flutter

I'm having multiple-choice questions in which I have to select multiple answers, for that, I'm using CheckBoxListTile, i'm able to add the selected values in a single list but i want to add selected values in a different list as selected values of question 1 in a different list and question 2 in different

Comment: Please take a look at the question guidelines to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that, I think you would need to create lists for different questions.

For example:

```
//Create your lists to store the answers in for your questions
List<bool> question1Value = [];
List<bool> question2Value = [];


CheckBoxListTile(
    title: Text("hello");
    onChanged(bool value) {
    // You can manipulate the data here in OnChanged
      question1Value.add(value);
      question2Value.add(value);
    }
  );
```

I hope this helped

Comment: i was following this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/52867589/10326315, here he is creating a single list for the selected category what I want is to create different list for all the questions? can you help me with this?