# How to check single checkboxes in a listview builder flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, checkbox

How do I use checkbox correctly in a listview in flutter, with the below code once i check one of the boxes the all checkbox in the listview gets clicked instead of the single one i clicked.

```
ListView.builder(
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                itemCount: bool_.length,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                  return CheckboxListTile(
                                    value: values,
                                    title: Text(bool_[index].name),
                                    onChanged: (selected) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        values = selected!;
                                        isSelected(selected, bool_[index].name);
                                      });
                                    },
                                  );
                                }),
```

the isSelected function is working fine am able to get the name of the checkbox according to which was clicked the only issue is all the checkbox get checked and unchecked at the same time

Comment: create a  check  Box  Widget  and  Using  Value Notifire

Comment: Pass `isSelected` function to your `value` instead of the variable. The variable is the same for all of the items in your list.

Comment: try this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/52867589/13973724

Comment: Refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74889012/13997210) for single and multiselect checkbox solution from list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use unique value for single selection ,

```
dynamic? values;
```

`value` should be type of `bool_[index]`.

```
                             ListView.builder(
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                itemCount: bool_.length,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                  return CheckboxListTile(
                                    value: values == bool_[index],
                                    title: Text(bool_[index].name),
                                    onChanged: (selected) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        if(values == bool_[index]){
                                           values = null;
                                        } else {
                                          values = bool_[index];
                                        }
                                        isSelected(selected, bool_[index].name);
                                      });
                                    },
                                  );
                                }),
```

If you want to allow multiple selection then you should have `List<dynamic> values = [];`, and `value = values.contains(bool_[index])` and in `onChanged`, you have add or remove based on condition `values.contains(bool_[index])`

I hope this helps